# obtener dinámicamente datos de un objeto a partir de variables estáticas

Tags: php, laravel-5

Buenas tardes

En PHP, Estoy tratando de obtener dinámicamente datos de un objeto a partir de variables estaticas, ejemplo:

```
$array = ['VARIABLE'] = 'dato1';
echo $objeto->{$array['VARIABLE']};
```

Hasta este punto todo esta bien, imprime sin error.. pero requiero hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$array = ['VARIABLE'] = "dato1->subdato1";
echo $objeto->{$array['VARIABLE']};
```

Pero en este caso no puedo obtener la propiedad solicitada, no funciona este apuntador, alguien sabe como puedo hacer??
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes desintegrar el valor de `$array['variable']` de la siguiente forma:

```php
$array['VARIABLE'] = 'dato1->subdato1';
list($dato, $subdato) = explode('->', $array['VARIABLE']);
$objeto->{$dato}->{$subdato};
```